# Hot to use custom CSS with Material UI and NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I am try to add some CSS to my components. However, when the website renders the custom CSS is always removed. I am styling my own pages and do not override the CSS of third parties, at least not consciously. I am using Material UI and NextJS and realised that while following  [this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs)
that all server-side CSS is removed. I suspect that this is the issue, but not sure how to work around it. The CSS is just custom to the component and follows the naming convention of Next :

```
[filename].modules.css
```

Does anyone know what do do?

Comment: can you share some of your code example